# bootstrap link not working and id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse" are not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

```
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="admin.php"> Admin panel</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

This div tag is not working in the admin.php file .
i am following the video as it is.
and the bootstrap link:
    
is not working as well.
please help me find a solution.

[image]

Comment: Did you also included bootstrap.js ?

Comment: I didn't pay attention to your picture ! Welcome to Stackoverflow :) Here people expect clear questions... so it's better to share a minimalist version of your code or more details about your environment. You are mentioning React in your Question Tags! Is it a React Bootstrap version... so react-bootstrap.min.js ?

Comment: i tried using bootstrap js, i am using xampp to display the output. Please let me know if you have any solution.

Comment: Ok can you load all required files (bootstrap.min.js, bootstrap.min.css...) from here: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/twitter-bootstrap  , load bootstrap.min.js after jQuery  And  show us your console log on that page?

Comment: And please share your code as text not as a picture !!!

Answer (score 0):

## Solution:

Add the bootstrap JS from its CDN

> https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js